# Unable to set Pthread Priority

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, thread-priority

I am unable to set Pthread priority using `pthread_attr_setschedparam()`. I have tried to resolve this issue but couldn't do it. I also consulted my text book which also uses the same function. I copied this code from book. Can you tell me how to set thread priority?

Here is the code:

```
void *Func(void *arg);
int main()
{
pthread_t tid[5];

pthread_attr_t *tattr;
struct sched_param param;
int pr,error,i;

do
{
if( (tattr=(pthread_attr_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_attr_t)) )==NULL)
{
    printf("Couldn't allocate memory for attribute object\n");
}
}while(tattr==NULL);

if(error=pthread_attr_init(tattr))
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Attribute initialization failed with error %s\n",strerror(error));
}

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    //scanf("%d",&pr);
        error = pthread_attr_getschedparam(tattr,&param);

        if(error!=0)
        {
            printf("failed to get priority\n");
        }

        param.sched_priority=10;
        error=pthread_attr_setschedparam(tattr,&param);

        if(error!=0)
        {
            printf("failed to set priority\n");
        }
/*  
    if(i%2==0)
    {
        if(error=pthread_attr_setdetachstate(tattr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED))

        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Failed to set thread attributes with error %s\n",strerror(error));
        }
    }
    else
        if(error=pthread_attr_setdetachstate(tattr,PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE))
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Failed to set thread attributes with error %s\n",strerror(error));
        }
*/      
        pthread_create(&tid[i],tattr,Func,NULL);


        printf("waiting for thread %d\n",i);
}

free(tattr);// release dynamically allocated memory

printf("All threads terminated\n");
return 0;
} 

 void *Func(void *arg)
{
printf("inside\n");

pthread_attr_t *tattr=(pthread_attr_t *)arg;
int state,error;

struct sched_param param;

error=pthread_attr_getdetachstate(tattr,&state);

if(error==0 && state==PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED)
{
    printf(" My state is DETACHED\n");
}
else
    if(error==0 && state==PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE)
    {
        printf(" My state is JOINABLE\n");
    }

error=pthread_attr_getschedpolicy(tattr,&param);

if(error==0)
{
    printf(" My Priority is %d\n",param.sched_priority);
}

return NULL;
}
```

Comment: What result are you getting? How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: I print `failed to get priority` for checking if priority of the thread is set or not. and It is always printed, which means priority is not set.

Comment: Are you running as root? Only root can increase priority (reduce nice value)

Comment: @anishsane `nice()` is specified to work process wide (even though on Linux it might work for threads also).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `pthread_attr_setschedparam` call is failing with "invalid parameter".  Your program will start with the default linux scheduling policy of `SCHED_OTHER`.  You can't change the priority of `SCHED_OTHER`.

From man (2) `sched_setscheduler`:

> SCHED_OTHER  can only be used at static priority 0.  SCHED_OTHER is the
>          standard Linux time-sharing scheduler that is  intended  for  all  processes that  do  not  require special static priority real-time mechanisms.

If you change the policy in the pthread attribute to another kind of schedule prior to attempting to change the priority your program will work.  Something like

```
for (i = 0;i < 5;i++)
{
    policy = SCHED_RR;

    error = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(tattr, policy);

    // insert error handling

    error = pthread_attr_getschedparam(tattr, &param);

    // insert error handling

    // yada yada yada ...
}
```

Comment: Also put in a `pthread_exit` in main and/or `pthread_join` the appropriate threads when you uncomment that detached/join code.

Answer (score 2):

This implementation worked for me (with this post help), it's straightforward:

```
pthread_t myThread;
pthread_attr_t *tattr;
struct sched_param param;
int error,policy, prio;

prio = 10;

tattr = (pthread_attr_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_attr_t));
error = pthread_attr_init(tattr);
cout << "init: " << error << endl;

error = pthread_attr_getschedparam(tattr,&param);
cout << "getschedparam: " << error << endl;

error = pthread_attr_setinheritsched(tattr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
cout << "setinheritsched: " << error << endl;

policy = SCHED_RR;
error = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(tattr, policy);
cout << "setschedpolicy = " << policy << ": " << error << endl;

param.sched_priority = prio;
error = pthread_attr_setschedparam(tattr ,&param);
cout << "setschedparam: " << error << endl;

error = pthread_create(&myThread,tattr,threadFunc,&numOfExecutions);
cout << "create: " << error << endl;

pthread_getschedparam(myThread,&policy,&param);
printf("policy:: %d pri :: %d\n",policy,param.sched_priority);
```

You can find my working code [here](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5125)

Answer (score 0):

```
 I created thread in main and set attributes using    
 pthread_attr_setechedparam(...) .Once the child thread is up and    running     i want to check this thread priority and policy set before using
 pthread_getschedparam( , , ). I executed code sudo still it is printing       zero for both pri and policy. Please find the code below.
 #include "stdio.h"

 #include "stdlib.h"

 #include "pthread.h"

void *Func(void *arg); 
int main() 
{

pthread_t tid;

 pthread_attr_t *tattr;

struct sched_param param;

 int pr,error,i;  

 int pol;
 do

  {

 if( (tattr=(pthread_attr_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_attr_t)) )==NULL)

 {

  printf("Couldn't allocate memory for attribute object\n");
  }


 }while(tattr==NULL);

  if(error=pthread_attr_init(tattr))
{
   fprintf(stderr,"Attribute initialization failed with error    %s\n",strerror(error));
  }

 //for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  //{
    error = pthread_attr_getschedparam(tattr,&param);

    if(error!=0)
    {
        printf("failed to get priority\n");
    }

    int policy=1;
    error=pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(tattr,policy);
   if(error!=0)
    {
        printf("failed to set priority\n");
    }

    param.sched_priority=10;
    error=pthread_attr_setschedparam(tattr,&param);

    if(error!=0)
    {
        printf("failed to set priority\n");
    }

    pthread_create(&tid,tattr,Func,NULL);

   pthread_getschedparam(tid,&pol,&param);
   printf("policy:: %d pri :: %d\n",pol,param.sched_priority);

    printf("waiting for thread %d\n",i);

    pthread_join(tid,NULL);
    free(tattr);// release dynamically allocated memory

    printf("All threads terminated\n");
    return 0; 
    }

    void *Func(void *arg)
    {
    printf("inside\n");
    int policy,err=0;
    struct sched_param p;
    err=pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(),&policy,&p);
    if(err!=0) 
     {
    printf("error\n");
     }
    printf("the priorty= %d policy =%d\n",p.sched_priority,policy);

    }
```