# Background thread with pthreads

Tags: c++, ios, pthreads

i'm using pthreads to create a background thread to load and do some tasks in background, but it lags the application a little bit as it's work is intense sometimes.

Is there any way i can set a lower priority or a different scheduling (or combination of both)  so the main thread has more CPU time to run?

Answer (score 2):

Use `pthread_attr_setschedparam`
http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_setschedparam

Use `SCHED_IDLE` scheduling policy to lower the priority of thread

Hope below SO links may help.

[How to increase thread priority in pthreads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649281/how-to-increase-thread-priority-in-pthreads)

[Equivalent of SetThreadPriority on Linux (pthreads)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876342/equivalent-of-setthreadpriority-on-linux-pthreads)

[Unable to set Pthread Priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964951/unable-to-set-pthread-priority)

Comment: Have you included sched.h ?

Comment: yes, but SCHED_IDLE is not defined, only SCHED_OTHER, SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR

Answer (score 2):

This does not verbatim answer your question, but
in the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH100-SW1)
Apple recommends to move away from threads and use "Dispatch Queues" or
 "Operation Queues" for asynchronous operations on OS X and iOS, for example

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    // ... background task
});
```

and `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW` is documented as

> Items dispatched to the queue run at low priority; the queue is
>   scheduled for execution after all default priority and high priority
>   queues have been scheduled.

Comment: @XavierAriasBotargues: Dispatch queues and blocks are available to C, C++ and Objective-C, compare http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/BlocksGCD/_index.html.